# how to map users that are defined in different sql databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I produce a windows App and the database is SQL Server 2005. In this database B I define a table for saving username and passwords. Now my company buys another app that has its own database with the same table for storing username and password.

They want to login to both applications with same username and password. what should I do in order to map the users of these two tables?

Comment: I think that most people will need a lot more information to give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how quickly you need to know about a new user in the "other" app - you could:

- create identical tables in the "other" database and periodically fill those from the master tables, e.g. with a nightly SSIS package job; with this, you have periodical updates, e.g. every night, every 4 hours etc., but the load on the server will be low

or:

- have a trigger on the "master" table and "replicate" each operation on that table (insert, update, delete) to the "slave" table in the other database; you have immediate updates, but the load on the server might be quite high for this

or:

- you could create a third database that contains just the user-management stuff, and have both "production" databases reference that "user" database for their user management; you could avoid any data duplication and both production systems would be using the same, up-to-date data at all times

or:

- you could use Windows authentication in the first place and get rid of all "yet-another-user-and-permissions-table" in any of the databases...